# How to set a UICollectionView as an exclusion path for a UITextView in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I need to set a UICollectionView as an exclusion path for a UITextView.

Ex:

+---------------------+
|*Lorum ipsum.......*|
|............................|
|............................|
+---------------------+
| ***Cell 11*** | ***Cell 12*** |
|----------+----------+
| ***Cell 21*** | ***Cell 22*** |
|----------+----------+
|*Lorum ipsum.......*|
|............................|
|............................|
+---------------------+

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried nesting a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`, or your custom cell?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have already achieved this using `UITableView`. I want to make use of **exclusion paths** which is available from iOS7 onwards. Which I feel will be more flexible.